# Debian + Flash Videos

Tags: flash, debian

I've just installed Debian in VirtualBox and I wanted to go check some stuff on youtube.
But everytime I get the message "An error Occured, please try again later". And it's not only for youtube. The flash in general seems to have issues. I checked what I had, I have Gnash installed. But it seems to be working wrong.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proprietary Adobe Flash Player, works fine.

The package is called "flashplugin-nonfree".

Comment: Can you add to the answer how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

@Tshepang : sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree

Stumbled upon the question, and wanted to make the answer available.

In case someone needs it, even if the post is very old :)